# React Input Form Value In An Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, react-forms

I am trying to build a **registration** form, I have built the **login** form and it works perfectly, but the registration form is quite off.

- First I used the `react-dev` tools to inspect what is going on and I realized that each `input` value coming from the **registration** form happens to be in an `array`.
- I went back to the **login** form to inspect and saw that the value of the `input` fields is in the right format (`strings`). But the value from each specific `input` field in the **registration** form is in an `array`.
  What could I be doing wrong?
- I tried to replicate what I did in the **login** form in the **registration** form, but it is still coming in an `array`.  Also, should `hooks` be kept in its own separate file?

This is what I see from the `react-dev` tools **for the registration form**.

[image]

Here is a code snippet of what I did.

```js
const Signup = (props) => {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { register, clearErrors, isAuthenticated, error } = authContext;
  const [loadBtn, updateLoadBtn] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    username: "",
    phoneNumber: "",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      successMessage();
      props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }

    if (error) {
      missingValue(error);
      updateLoadBtn(false);
      clearErrors();
    }

    //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [isAuthenticated, error, props.history]);

  const { firstName, lastName, email, password, username, phoneNumber } = user;
  const onChange = (e) =>
    setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: [e.target.value] });

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    updateLoadBtn(true);
    if (
      !firstName ||
      !lastName ||
      !email ||
      !password ||
      !username ||
      !phoneNumber
    ) {
      missingValue("Please enter all fields");
      updateLoadBtn(false);
      clearErrors();
    } else {
      register({
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
        password,
        username,
        phoneNumber,
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <ToastContainer />
      <RegContainer className="container-fluid py-4">
        <RegInfo />
        <RegColumn
          onChange={onChange}
          onSubmit={onSubmit}
          firstName={firstName}
          lastName={lastName}
          email={email}
          password={password}
          phoneNumber={phoneNumber}
          loadBtn={loadBtn}
        />
      </RegContainer>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

That is the file responsible for handling the **registration**.

Here is the custom component

```js
const RegColumn = ({
  firstName,
  onSubmit,
  onChange,
  lastName,
  username,
  password,
  phoneNumber,
  email,
  loadBtn,
}) => {
  const bodyStyle = document.querySelector("body").style;
  bodyStyle.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(to bottom, #F6F6F2, #C2EDCE)";
  bodyStyle.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
  bodyStyle.overflow = "hidden";
  bodyStyle.height = "100%";
  bodyStyle.fontFamily = "Rubik, sans-serif";
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div id="reg-column">
        <h3 style={{ color: "#388087" }}>REGISTRATION</h3>
        <Form divid="form-row1-label" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <LabelContainer id="form-row1-label">
            <LabelContainer id="firstNameLabel">
              <LabelInfo labelfor="firstName" labeltitle="First Name" />
            </LabelContainer>
            <LabelContainer id="lastNameLabel">
              <LabelInfo labelfor="lastName" labeltitle="Last Name" />
            </LabelContainer>
          </LabelContainer>
          <InputContainer id="form-row1-input">
            <InputContainer id="firstNameInput">
              <Input
                type="text"
                name="firstName"
                value={firstName}
                id="firstName"
                onChange={onChange}
              />
            </InputContainer>
            <InputContainer id="lastNameInput">
              <Input
                type="text"
                onChange={onChange}
                name="lastName"
                value={lastName}
                id="lastName"
              />
            </InputContainer>
       // ...
```

Thank you.

Comment: Remove brackets on on `e.target.value`; it makes the value an `array`.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out, it fixed the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `Signup` form, you have this...

```js
  // ...
  const onChange = (e) =>
    setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: [e.target.value] });
```

What's happening above?

- The `onChange()` is responsible for updating the values to be submitted.
- Within `setUser`, you are passing a value as a literal `array` using `[e.target.value]`

Solution:

- Remove the literal array `[]` and pass value as it's received i.e. `e.target.value`
- The left hand side, `e.target.name`, is fine since you are actually using a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

You can also read more about [handling forms in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).